# Dynamic line between concentric circles in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What is the best way to create a diagonal line between the space of two concentric circles that will adjust in length depending on the space between the outer and inner circle as I want to be able to change the diameter of the outer and inner circle and have the line adjust dynamically.

This is a simple static version of my code: jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaevonz/mowahL2v/204/

This is the full dynamic version of my code with jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/Kaevonz/fkbrpL54/46/

This is essentially what I am trying to recreate: I want the wall thickness label to adjust dynamically. [image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.elem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div1 {
  border-top: 3px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-left: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-right: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  background: white;
}

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.div3 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div4 {
  border-top: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.div5 {
  border: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem div1"></div>
  <div class="elem div2">
    <div class="elem div3">
      <div class="elem div5">
      </div>
      <div class="elem div4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add that line by drawing a radius on the larger circle using a pseudo element and covering up the part that is within the smaller circle by giving the smaller circle a higher z index (as it already has a background color set).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.elem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div1 {
  border-top: 3px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-left: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-right: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  height: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  background: white;
}

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 290px;
  height: 290px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.div2::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50% - 0.5px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  background: gray;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: right center;
}

.div3 {
  border: 1px solid #0DA8AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.div4 {
  border-top: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.div5 {
  border: 0.5px dashed black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem div1"></div>
  <div class="elem div2">
    <div class="elem div3">
      <div class="elem div5">
      </div>
      <div class="elem div4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the line adapt in size even if increase the outer circle size?

Comment: Yes, it is sized relative to the outer circle and the bit under the inner circle is hidden so it adapts to both. Why not try changing sizes of the circles to make sure?